# Domino LDAP : Get email of all users in a group

Tags: ibm-domino, ldap

I'm trying to get all the list of all users that belong to a specific *group* from a Domino 8 LDAP server using ldapsearch.

I've tried pretty much every possible variant of the following filters with no success :

```
(memberOf=CN=GroupName)
(dominoaccessgroups=CN=GroupName)
```

*Note that the attribute dominoaccessgroups shows up in LDAP browser, and contains the name of the group the user belongs. For each group that the user belongs to, there is a matching dominoaccessgroups attribute for the user object*

No matter what I try, it always returns an empty result set.

Any help welcome, I've been struggling with this all afternoon.

**Edit**

As posted below, I can get the list of all users in a group by querying the member attribute on a group. However, my original question was not clear on that point : I don't want to extract the DN's of the users, but the value of another attribute (in my case, the mail attribute). Is there anyway to do that without running two separate queries (one for the group members' DNs, and one for the mail attribute of all the DNs returned by the first) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't quite parse what you mean by "...that belong to a specific from a Domino 8 LDAP server...".

But if you search for example for "objectClass=dominoGroup"

```
ldapsearch -h localhost "objectClass=dominoGroup"
```

You get a list of all you groups. And if you look at the return values, you will see, that each group has a list of "member" attributes, listing all the members of a group.

So with

```
ldapsearch -h localhost "(&(objectClass=dominoGroup)(CN=LocalDomainAdmins))" member
```

You would get the list of all members of the "LocalDomainAdmins" group.

HTH

Comment: I edited my post so that it is now parsable.

Comment: How would you know entity type (user or group) from all members list (as domino will return all members.)? 
as we can assign a group to a group.

Answer (score 0):

The object class for groups are called `groupOfNames`. The following filter should do a LDAP search for a group:

```
(&(objectclass=groupofnames)(cn=GroupName))
```